# Convert File Uploaded Using PHP from .DOC to .PDF

Tags: php

I have a form written in PHP (server running PHP 5.3) where the user uploads a file to the server and stores some stuff in a database. The files being uploaded are going to be Microsoft Word .DOC files. For users to view the files after they have been uploaded in various instances, I need the file they download/view to be a .PDF. Is there any way on a Windows server, using PHP or some other web programming language, that I can have the file automatically convert to a .PDF after it has been uploaded and save that file in addition to storing the .DOC file?

The web page is hosted on an internal server that does not have external internet access, so using a 3rd party API is not feasible. Preferably something that is lightweight and doesn't require installation of a lot of other programs would be great.

**EDIT: Added lines of code added to php.ini file.**
I added this line of code to the php.ini file which points to the correct directory where I saved the ZendFramework Library.
`include_path = ".;C:\PHP\ZendFramework\library"`

I just added it below
`; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"`
`;include_path = ".:/php/includes"`
`;`
`; Windows: "\path1;\path2"`
`;`
`; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"`
`; http://php.net/include-path`

Answer (score 2):

You likely want to use the [Livedocx library.](http://www.livedocx.com) There is a Zend Framework component that can handle this. [Here is more info](http://www.phplivedocx.org) about using it.